# Can I copy my personal emblem to my platoon?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

I have an emblem on my soldier that I really like and I would like to use it a slightly altered version for my platoon. Can I somehow easily copy the emblem over so I can then make those slight adjustments? I really would not like to have to create the whole emblem again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.

You have to follow [these steps to export your emblem](http://www.reddit.com/r/bf4emblems/comments/1nw3jy/):

## Exporting your emblem

1. Navigate to the Emblem editor and select the emblem you wish to export.
2. Use the appropriate keyboard shortcut to bring up the console screen for your web browser.
3. Paste the following code into the console and hit 'Enter':

   ```
   $('body').html('<pre style="color:#000;">emblem.emblem.load('+JSON.stringify(emblem.emblem.data,null,2)+');</pre>');
   ```
4. You should now be brought to a new page that shows you all the code you want. Copy and paste this into your text editor.

Once you have your emblem copied, bring up your platoon (**you must be platoon leader (afaik) to edit the platoon's emblem**).  Navigate to the create a new emblem page and open the console again.   Simply paste in that code you previously copied and save.

Comment: I tested this from a Windows OS running Chrome (Ctrl + Shift + J to bring up the console) and was able to get it to work.

Comment: I got some sort of error for using locked shapes, but it worked after removing the premium shapes from the produced javascript table.